# After passing Object to another ViewController the object becomes nil, Swift?

Tags: swift

I am passing a `Venue` object from the `PreferencesVC` to `DiscoverVC` by declaring an instance of the class and setting the `venue` variable to the object being passed.

By the time the code executes `beginLoadView()` the `Venue` object is `nil` and therefore the `if` statement incorrectly executes

Console output:

[image]

```
Class PreferencesVC: UIViewController{

    @IBAction func doneBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        print("inside doneBtnTapped selectedVenue.name: \(selectedVenue?.name ?? "selectedVenue is nil")")

        guard let discoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscoverVC") as? DiscoverVC else { return }

        discoverVC.venue = self.selectedVenue!

        DataService.run.updateUserDiscoveryPreferences(forUID: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, discoverableBool: discoverable!, preferences: preferences) { (success) in

            self.dismissDetail()
        }

    }//end func
}



    Class DiscoverVC: UIViewController{

         var venue: Venue?{
        didSet{
            print("DiscoverVC venue name: \(venue?.name ?? "venue name")")
        }
    }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("inside viewWillDisappear")

        venue = nil

    }//end func

         override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

                print("inside viewWillAppear")
                beginLoadView()
    }
         func beginLoadView(){

                print("inside beginLoadView venue.name: \(venue?.name ?? "'venue' is nil")")

                if venue != nil {

                    print("Venue var is not empty venue.name: \(String(describing: venue?.name))")

                    Utilities.run.showSVHUDWithStatus(uiView: self.view, status: "Discovering")
                    setupViews()
                    getCurrentLoggedUserProfile()
                    showHudAndStartUpdatingLocation()
                    observeUsersChanges()

                } else {

                    print("Venue var is empty venue.name: \(String(describing: venue?.name))")

                    Utilities.run.showSVHUDWithStatus(uiView: self.view, status: "Discovering")
                    fetchNearestVenue()
                    getCurrentLoggedUserProfile()

                }// end if-else

            }//end func
         }
        }

    Class VenueDetailsVC: UIViewController{

        func presentDiscoverVC(){

            guard let discoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscoverVC") as? DiscoverVC else { return }

            discoverVC.venue = self.venue!
            discoverVC.showBackButton = true

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.presentDetail(discoverVC)
            }

        }//end func

    }
```

Comment: Can you check is here `selectedVenue` is nil? `discoverVC.venue = self.selectedVenue!` And where did you push discoverVC? I don't see it.

Comment: Where are you presenting `discoverVC`?

Comment: @Andrew  I have edited my question to include an output of the object value when doneBtnTapped is tapped. The object is not nil.

Comment: @PGDev I have edited my question...I am presenting it from `VenueDetailsVC`

Comment: From where do you want to present DiscoverVC? PreferencesVC or VenueDetailsVC? Moreover the code you pasted here won't even compile. And why all the 3 controllers aren't inheriting from UIViewControllers? Kindly add the proper code.

Comment: @PGDev apologies I manually entered the class text and copied the relating functions (instead of pasting the entire class). I want to present `DiscoverVC` from `VenueDetailsVC`, the `beginLoadView()` will either load the selected venue details OR search for the nearest venue and load those instead, for that I am doing the check in the `if` statement. I then have a PreferenceVC to updated some settings and so I am "going back" to DiscoverVC and wish to load the venue that was originally selected, hence the passing of the `Venue` object between VCs.

Comment: @PGDev I should also point out that I am setting the `venue = nil` in my `DiscoverVC` `viewWillDisappear`, but I am assigning it a value in my `PreferencesVC`

Answer (score 0):

As I saw, discoverVC variable is not use to present and discoverVC variable you did set venue is diffirent DiscoverVC object presented. You can try print address of discoverVC and in viewWillAppear.